# MiniTest fails but UnitTest works for inheritance

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-2, minitest

I have a code in Rails ***v2.3*** as follows with MiniTest ***v4.7.5***:

## Class

```
class Pdf
 def generator_class
   return GeneratePDF::Image
 end
end
```

## Module

```
module GeneratePDF
 class Image
   # ...
 end
end
```

## Testcase

```
require_relative '../test_helper'
class PdfTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 should "return the generator class" do
   pdf = Factory.create(:pdf)
   assert_equal GeneratePDF::Image, pdf.generator_class
 end
end
```

When I run the test with minitest it fails with following error:

```
Failure:
<GeneratePDF::Image> expected but was <Pdf::GeneratePDF::Image>.
```

But the same testcase is passed with UnitTest.

## Work around

I am able to resolve the issue by prefixing the scope resolution in return statement.

```
class Pdf
 def generator_class
   return ::GeneratePDF::Image
 end
end
```

Please let me know why its behaving differently and best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: What happens if you don't use a Factory to create the pdf instance?

Comment: Same thing is happening when we don't use Factory.